# "Fire and forget" class in ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I needed to make a custom `UIAlertView` for my app, and I came across [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics/) article describing how to do it.  I have since made a few changes to it, but the more important fact remains that this class does not function as a "Fire and forget" alert, the way that `UIAlertView` does, because ARC does not allow one to call `retain`.

So basically, I want to be able to utilize my custom alert view the same way as a normal alert view, so I can create and display one like this:

```
CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc] init];//Init presumably does the view setup
[alert show];
```

So my question is, how can I get this object not to deallocate as soon as it goes out of scope when working in an ARC project, without creating a `strong` reference to it in the calling class?

**EDIT**

I suppose it is important to mention, that in order to get the full freedom of view customizability I wanted, I had to make this a new ViewController class, it is **NOT** a subclass of `UIAlertView`

**EDIT 2**

I'm sorry, I didn't look at my link too closely, I had the wrong tutorial linked originally.  [THIS](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html) is the correct tutorial I based my view off of

Comment: [show] bumps the ref count, so your local variable is not the only handle to the object anymore. Fire and forget away.

Comment: It isn't a subclass, its new view controller so that it can be instantiated from a nib, or from a storyboard scene

Comment: UIAlertView works by adding another `UIWindow` onto the window hierarchy, which makes UIWindow retain it. Try to mimic this behavior in your application.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII How do I add the view to the window hierarchy, and retain the view controller's behavior?  For example, I am making an alert-view style passcode entry, all of the various buttons are hooked up to IBActions in my storyboard.  If I simply present it as a view, I will lose the controller class, and be just left with the view wont I?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII in my experience `UIWindow` objects are not retained by the window hierarchy, so you will need someone to retain the window regardless. (this behavior makes sense: if noone needs a window, it vanishes)

Comment: The main window is retained by the app delegate. It's in your code, the boilerplate parts. So yes, you need to retain a window manually.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev this was about adding a second UIWindow, not the main window.

Comment: My point was that windows are not retained by the magic gnomes in Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mimic the way `UIAlertView` works, you need to create a new `UIWindow` object, initialize it properly and show it using `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`. Beware that this will present, but *not* retain the window. If the reference count of the window drops to zero, the window is removed from the screen.

You want to deliberately create a retain cycle, which you break once your alertview is dismissed.

I.e. your customalertview class creates and retains a `UIWindow`, and the `UIWindow` retains its subview: your customalertview class. Then, by releasing the `UIWindow`, the window will release your customalertview.

Comment: I've got the display happening right, I'm just wondering how I can get the object to not destroy itself once it goes out of scope

Comment: Like I said, you need to introduce a retain cycle. In one project, I solved it by subclassing `UIWindow`, and having it retain a controller object, which retained the window. Once the window decides it's over (`self.controller = nil`), or the controller does so (`self.window = nil`) the cycle is broken and everything is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a strong reference to your subclass instance while it is needed. You could do this, for example, by presenting your object in a view controller (since the view controller hierarchy is maintained strongly) or by having a class-level reference to all instances of your class which are still needed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "class-level reference"?

Comment: I mean to make, for example, a static variable in your .m file which points to a NSMutableArray of "in use" instances of your class. (You'll then need some mechanism for your instances to register and de-register themselves from the list.)

Comment: I see, that is one way of bypassing ARC's ban on calls to `retain`